# Cumulative product of an array: std::accumulate vs loop

Tags: c++, accumulate

Let's say I want to compute the cumulative product of the first `k` elements of an array.

```cpp
int arr[8] = {3, 5, 7, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2};
int k = 3;
```

Which one is the best option in terms of performance?

**Option 1. Ordinary for loop**

```cpp
int result = 1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    result *= arr[i];
}
```

**Option 2. Accumulate**

```
result = std::accumulate(std::begin(arr),
                         std::begin(arr) + k,
                         1,
                         [](const int& x, const int &y) { return x*y; });
```

I am especially interested in cases where `k` is small, for example `k = 3` or `k = 4`. Is the fancy C++11 way of doing things actually worth it in this case?

Comment: "best" in terms of what? One main reason to use algorithms rather than loops is readability and expressiveness, which is largely opinion based

Comment: btw accumulate isnt the "fancy C++11 way" with [`std::multiplies`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/multiplies) this was possible long before C++11, and also after C++11 it is preferable over a handwritten lambda

Comment: In terms of performance. Initial post edited.

Comment: For readability, there is no question about what the `for` loop is doing... Worth understanding both, "style-points v. readabilty, style-points v. readability, ..." There is a balance to be struct.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin There's no question about what std::accumulate is doing either. Both are equally readable in my opinion. It's a trade-off between style-points and style-points.

Comment: Of course not [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) -- you miss the point. There is no question about what anything does when you can simply look it up on cppreference, but that in itself is the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are fine; neither is bad. The choice between them is matter of opinion.

The latter is hardly "fancy C++11", since the only meaningful C++11 feature used is the lambda which can be replaced with `std::multiplies` or in general case with a function object in "fancy C++98". (Yes `std::begin` was added in C++11 as well, but you can simply remove it as it isn't necessary).

---

I want to suggest a ranges alternative. Unfortunately C++20 didn't include `std::ranges::accumulate`, so I have to suggest using a non-standard algorithm instead:

```
std::ranges::subrange sub1(arr, arr + k);
auto sub2 = std::views::counted(arr, k); // alternative
std::span sub3(arr, k);                  // less general alternative

// no standard ranges alternative for this yet
auto result = ranges::accumulate(sub1, 1, std::multiplies<>{});
```

---

> Which one is the best option in terms of performance?

Both/neither. Any decent optimiser should produce identical assembly.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: Using algorithms rather than hand written loops is not so much about performance! You can see a possible implementation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). You will notice that it is just a loop that you could write yourself as well.

---

The better comparison is the handwritten loop vs:

```
auto result = std::accumulate(std::begin(arr),
                              std::begin(arr) + k,
                              1,
                              std::multiplies<>{});
```

This is equivalent to the hand written loop and does not require C++11 (only for `auto`, `std::begin` and `std::end`, and `std::multiplies<>` requires C++14, but before you would use `std::multiplies<int>`).

The advantage of the algorithm is expressiveness and readability. You cannot give a name to a loop, while the algorithms name is telling what it does. Also the binary operator and initial value are more easily replacable. The initial value is not necessarily of the same type as the elements, and the return type of `accumulate` is deduced from it. If you want to multiply more values and avoid overflow you merely have to replace the `1` with `1L`. If you later decide that you don't want to multiply, but add you merely have to replace `std::multiplies` with `std::plus`. With the handwritten loop such refactoring requires to dig into details and consider the whole loop instead of changing only the one detail you want to change. Other than that, it is opinion-based which one is "better". Performance-wise no big difference is to be expected, if any.

---

Note that the changes that came with C++11 and C++14 are not just about being "fancy". Before C++11 the call would look like this:

```
int result = std::accumulate(arr,                        // <- int
                             arr + k,
                             1,                          // <- int
                             std::multiplies<int>{});    // <- int
```

Here the type used for the result appears 3 times, which makes the point above about easily replacing the type of the initial value moot. The changes that came with `auto` and a functor with templated `operator()` are not about fancyness, but they decrease chances of making mistakes measurably.

---

TL;DR

For a loop as simple as yours I would probably use the hand written loop. It is clear and readable and unlikely any fancy algorithm can make it more performant.

Comment: Just a nitpick about language levels: freestanding `std::begin` wasn't available pre-C++11 either.